# Proxy settings for Selenium@library with robot Framework and VNCserver

Tags: linux, selenium, proxy, robotframework

Hi I am writing testcases in robot Framework with Selenum2Library.
I am running my Product on another VM with Proxy settings and Selenium on other machine.
If there's no Proxy I can run selenium on one and product on other.
Is there any way we can bypass proxy settings, and access the product???

I am working on Fedora and trying to access red hat ironport account.

any help is more then welcome.

THanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try generate custom firefox profile in which you could set your custom firefox settings.

On my system firefox's profile (which robot framework uses by default) locates at /usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/SeleniumLibrary/firefoxprofile/.

As I understand from doc from /usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/SeleniumLibrary/**init**.py you can copy that dir, edit and then use it:

Start Selenium Server -firefoxProfileTemplate C:\\the\\path # Uses custom Firefox profile